# I cannot open PDF copied from Linux system

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer

I copied several PDF files from openSUSE to Windows 10 system, but I cannot open them from Windows 10. It gives me an error:

> can not locate file

The file has a size of 0. I can open all these files under Linux system by mounting the disk of Windows 10. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: If they are size 0 then they didn't copy correctly.  How did you do the copy?

Comment: Check the names of the files. Give them some small nice names and then recopy.

Comment: Is it possible the directory that you are trying to move the file is full? Meaning there is no room or storage available to copy the file from Linux to Windows?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned. The if the file size is 0 than there seems to be an error or an issue when moving/copying it to Windows. In some cases simply dragging and dropping the file does not always transfer the file in to the area in Windows which you are moving it to.

In some cases you may just need to copy and paste the file, with the keyboard shortcut or right-clicking.

I believe this can occur When cp copies a file, it tries to preserve its "sparseness" using heuristics, but this would be true for Linux not when trying to copy across to Windows in this case.

You could also try to isolate the issue and see if it is strictly based between the two operating systems. Perhaps attempt to copy a smaller file-size, or use a cloud based system to uploa

Comment: thanks a lot. in the file exploered, the file has a size, but when i righ click to view the propertity, the size is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before. I resolved it by copying over my files over the terminal. 
first you have to mount the windows file system on a folder or `cd` to it in the `/media` folder then copy over the files you want with `sudo cp [souce-file] [dest-file]`.